# custom taxonomy sort order not working

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom taxonomy named product_categories.

It has three fields :

1. for banner image
2. for category image and
3. for sort order.

I have added 10 categories in it giving its sort order input also.

Now i want to show this in sorting order but it is not working.

**In pt-categories input for sort order is this**

```
<tr class="form-field">
<th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="cat_sort_order"><?php _e('Product Sort Order'); ?></label></th>
<td>
    <input id="banner-url" name="term_meta[sort_order]" type="text" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $term_meta['sort_order'] ? $term_meta['sort_order'] : ''; ?>" />
    <span class="description"><?php _e('&nbsp;'); ?></span>
</td>
```

**Saving funtion is this**

```
    function save_product_categories_custom_fields($term_id)
    {
    if (isset($_POST['term_meta'])) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $term_meta = get_option("taxonomy_term_$t_id");
        $cat_keys = array_keys($_POST['term_meta']);
        foreach ($cat_keys as $key) {
            if (isset($_POST['term_meta'][$key])) {
                $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
            }
        }
     //save the option array
        update_option("taxonomy_term_$t_id", $term_meta);
    }
}
```

**Here is the categories called**

```
function getLatestProducts() { 
$args = array(
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_type' => 'products', 
  'posts_per_page' => 12,
  'meta_key'        => '_cus_sort_order',
  'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num', 
  'order' => 'ASC'
);
?>
<?php
                $args = array(
                'orderby' => 'name',
                );
                $terms = get_terms('product_categories', $args);
                foreach($terms as $term) {      
               $prod_meta = get_option("taxonomy_term_".$term->term_id);
                    ?>
                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, 'product_categories') ?>">
                <?php
                    echo '<img src="'.$prod_meta['img'].'" title="" alt=""></a>';    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="product-name">
                <h5>
                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, 'product_categories') ?>">
                <?php echo $term->name;?>
                </a>
                </h5>
```

It is showing the categories names and images but not in sorted order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code of **Categories Called**

**Corrected Code**

```
function getLatestProducts() { 
    $args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'products', 
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'meta_key'        => '_cus_sort_order',
    'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num, name', 
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
            $terms = get_terms('product_categories', $args);
            foreach($terms as $term) {      
           $prod_meta = get_option("taxonomy_term_".$term->term_id);
                ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, 'product_categories') ?>">
            <?php
                echo '<img src="'.$prod_meta['img'].'" title="" alt=""></a>';    ?>
            </div>
            <div class="product-name">
            <h5>
            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, 'product_categories') ?>">
            <?php echo $term->name;?>
            </a>
            </h5>
```

I have removed an array of argument which is called after main arguments array. As the below mentioned argument array is overriding the above mentioned arguments array.

**Removed Arguments Array**

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i am calling the categories.

Comment: Have you tried my answer whether it is working or not?

Comment: it is not working. i have given number that is 1 2 3 in sorting order

Comment: it is not displaying like that.

Comment: i have to tell you this sir that sorting input is also in categories and want to apply on categories

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Mehul's answer, your saving function has also some mistakes.

Have you checked previously saved sort orders of your categories ?

`"taxonomy_term_$t_id"` should be `"taxonomy_term_" . $t_id` . Otherwise you are saving everything as `taxonomy_term_$t_id` option and not with a dynamic term id.

```
function save_product_categories_custom_fields($term_id)
{
if (isset($_POST['term_meta'])) {
    $t_id = $term_id;
    $term_meta = get_option("taxonomy_term_" . $t_id);
    $cat_keys = array_keys($_POST['term_meta']);
    foreach ($cat_keys as $key) {
        if (isset($_POST['term_meta'][$key])) {
            $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
        }
    }
 //save the option array
    update_option("taxonomy_term_" . $t_id, $term_meta);
}
```

}

Comment: then what should i change in it sir

Comment: and if change this "taxonomy_term_" . $t_id then will there be any effect on my previous categories

Comment: If i used this then new category is not added.